# WPF ComboBox drop down freezes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, .net-2.0

After populating a WPF ComboBox dynamically and clicking into it, I am experiencing a short delay (3-5 seconds). In our project, this is unacceptable.

**How can I modify combobox items dynamically without producing that drop-down freeze afterwards?**

I am using .NET 2.0 and cannot upgrade.

I have tried using ItemSource Binding and decoupling from Dispatcher, but this did not help. When tabbing into the ComboBox by keyboard, there is no delay (in that case the DropDown list doesn't show).

Here's a minimal working example. To reproduce the delay,

1. Click the button, then the ComboBox
2. Do that again

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Name="comboBox"/>
    <Button   Grid.Row="1" Click="button_Click">Add Items</Button>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox.Items.Clear();
        comboBox.Items.Add("Item 1");
        comboBox.Items.Add("Item 2");
        comboBox.Items.Add("Item 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get anything in the Output for debug?

Comment: No, debug output is empty.

Comment: I have tried above code in .net framework 4.6.2, and it display result in split second. Another option is bind combo after page initialize (InitializeComponent) and set combo hidden, on button click make combo visible.

Comment: This is not an option. In my real project we are stuck to .NET 2.0 and the combobox is refreshed dynamically. Remember this is only a minimal example.

Comment: I had a look at the `VirtualisingStackPanel` as `ComboBox.ItemsPanel` but it is available only from .NET 3 onwards. So if you can then possibly you could paginate your data? Load first 100 records into the dropdown and then load more when user scrolls the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks. I think we can rule out that. In my example I have only three items, and it's freezing when clicking into the combobox :(